# What butterfly species is represented on this painting?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I am wondering if the butterflies represented on this painting correspond to a real species.
Do you know if this is the case and if yes, what species they belong to? Or at least, what species could have inspired the author?

I think the flowers that butterflies land on are probably poppies.

The painting is from the book "Ehon mushi erami" (Picture Book of Crawling Creatures) by Kitagawa Utamaro, a Japanese painter (the book was published in 1788).

[image: Butterflies Utamaro]

Answer (score 3):

If this were in the US, I'd say this was a cabbage butterfly (*[Pieris rapae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pieris_rapae)*), which is white save a black or gray spot or two on each wing. But it's not in the US; it's in Japan.

Being interested in most things natural, I Googled "all-white butterfly Japan".

I think you've come across a partial depiction of a story, not an attempt to paint an actual, realistic butterfly. Googling "all-white butterfly Japan", there were many hits with the same theme: the soul is like the [white butterfly](https://www.butterflyinsight.com/butterfly-legends-japan-white-butterfly.html) and love is the power that transforms.

From [another site](https://kamcord.com/what-does-it-mean-to-see-a-white-butterfly/):

> In Japanese folklore, the white butterfly symbolizes selfless love stronger than death, as told in an ancient tale of lovers named Takahama and Akiko. In modern-day Japan, the moral of the myth has been retained, and a white butterfly sighting continues to hold special significance.

I don't know how true this is, as I do not much trust everything I read on the Internet. But it appears, as [here](https://jpninfo.com/103860), often on searches varying the words.

If it were meant to be an actual white butterfly, cabbages are also common in Japan, as seen on this stamp:

[image]

If someone could read the writing on the painting, it might help a *lot*.